# C# - How to shorten a string

Tags: c#, string

I have a piece of code and I need to shorten a string that I have in a variable. I was wondering how could I do this. My code is below.

```
string test = Console.ReadLine();
if(string.Length > 5)
{
    //shorten string
}
Console.WriteLine(test);
Console.ReadLine();
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use [`string.Substring`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.substring%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

```
test = test.Substring(0, 5);
```

`Substring(0,5)` will take the first five characters of the string, so assigning it back will shorten it to that length.

Answer (score 3):

Here is how:

```
test = test.Substring(0,5);
```

Please note also that your `if` statement is wrong. It should check the `test` variable like this:

```
if(test.Length > 5)
```

Answer (score 1):

You are doing the comparation wrong, you must compare with **test** instead with the property **string**

```
string test = Console.ReadLine();
if(test.Length > 5)
{
    //shorten string
    test = test.Substring(0,5)
}
Console.WriteLine(test);
Console.ReadLine();
```

With Substring you will get from character 0 to 4, adjust it to your need